# I am trying to show scroll indicator in bottom when get to limit

Tags: react-native

I am trying to show the bottom indicator and then show more data when it reach the limit, I need only to know what the name of the footer indicator in ScrollView in react native

I am trying to show the bottom indicator and then show more data when it reach the limit, I need only to know what the name of the footer indicator in ScrollView in react native
`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, Button, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
state = {
    // Sample data
    items: [
    { item: "Item 1", price: "10", id: 1 },
    { item: "Item 2", price: "20", id: 2 },
    { item: "Item 3", price: "30", id: 3 },
    { item: "Item 4", price: "40", id: 4 },
    { item: "Item 5", price: "50", id: 5 },
    { item: "Item 6", price: "60", id: 6 },
    { item: "Item 7", price: "70", id: 7 },
    { item: "Item 8", price: "80", id: 8 },
    { item: "Item 9", price: "90", id: 9 },
    { item: "Item 10", price: "100", id: 10 },
    { item: "Item 11", price: "110", id: 11 },
    { item: "Item 12", price: "120", id: 12 },
    { item: "Item 13", price: "130", id: 13 },
    { item: "Item 14", price: "140", id: 14 },
    { item: "Item 15", price: "150", id: 15 },
    ],
};
render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        <ScrollView> // use of ScrollView Component
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
            <View key={item.id}>
            <View style={styles.summary}>
                <Text style={styles.summaryText}>
                {item.item} <Text style={styles.amount}>
                    ${item.price}</Text>
                </Text>
                <Button title="Order" color="#FFC107"
                    onPress={() => { }} />
            </View>
            </View>
        ))}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );
}
}

// Screen styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
screen: {
    margin: 20,
},
summary: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
},
summaryText: {
    fontFamily: "openSansBold",
    fontSize: 18,
},
amount: {
    color: "#C2185B",
},
});

export default App;
```

`

Comment: If you would like to add a 'More' button in the bottom of the scrollview, can you just put a button component before the closing tag of scrollview?

Comment: However, if you are looking for infinite scroll for the data list, it is suggested that using `FlatList` instead of `ScrollView` with map function. You can add function to `onEndReached` props in `FlatList` to retrieve more data and then append to data list.

Comment: I already add onEndReached but I need to add scroll indicator when it reach end

Comment: scroll indicator should be visible when you are scrolling, or you are talking about other component?

Comment: footer component : loading when scroll. I need to add circular loading when the list reach the limit show circular  loading before loading other items

Comment: so do you mean a loading indicator?

Comment: yes loading indicator

Comment: You can try `<ActivityIndicator />` offered by [react-native library](https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator). Just do a conditional render for this loading indicator in the footer component of  `FlatList`.

Comment: but I am not using flat list I used scrollView

Comment: You may use `onScroll` props in the `ScrollView` to [determine whether the list is scrolled to the bottom or not](https://gist.github.com/jbutko/33832e50f3d95a73842e763b3791f586). Then add conditional loading component in the end of the scrollView

Comment: I am trying that but it stil didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For illustration it is better to for provide an example.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, Button, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

class TestScreen extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [...],
        loading: false
    };

    isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
      let paddingToBottom = 20;
      return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.screen}>
                <ScrollView
                  onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
                    //Check whether the scrollview is reaching bottom
                    if (this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {  
                      this.setState({loading: true});
                    }
                  }}
                  scrollEventThrottle={400}
                > 
                {...Your Map Function}
                {
                  this.state.loading && <ActivityIndicator />
                }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

It is better to implement this kind of list in a `FlatList`, but it is up to you. Enjoy :)

**Edit: added FlatList Component for your reference**

```
<FlatList 
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    data={this.state.items}
    onEndReached={()=>{
      this.setState({loading: true});
    }}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => {
      return(
        <View key={item.id}>
          <View style={styles.summary}>
              <Text style={styles.summaryText}>
              {item.item} <Text style={styles.amount}>
                  ${item.price}</Text>
              </Text>
              <Button title="Order" color="#FFC107"
                  onPress={() => { }} />
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }}
    ListFooterComponent={()=>{
      return (this.state.loading && <ActivityIndicator />)
    }}
 />
```